# Discretization of $W^{1,\infty} (\mathbb R^N, \mathbb R^N)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

I am working on a shape differentiation problem. I have a theoretical result that I want to implement numerically. Does anyone know of a reference for a discretization (finite sequence of subspaces with good properties) of the space $W^{1,\infty} (\mathbb R^N, \mathbb R^N)$?

Thanks in advance,
D

Comment: Please expain the second $\mathbb R^N$ in $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R^N, \mathbb R^N)$. Also [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Other_examples) says that the space is just Lipschitz functions. Maybe, you can use piecewise-linear (bilinear, N-linear) spline for your case, but there's really no difference between discrete variants of $W^{1,k}$ for different $k$.

Comment: Since $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N, \mathbb{R}^N)$ is not separable, it is quite difficult (if not impossible), to approximate functions in the norm of $W^{1,\infty}$.